# Колёса моего велика спущены/спущенны

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Колёса моего велика спущены/спущенны.

> Её стандарты спущены/спущенны.

> Коты, когда я пришёл, были, к счастью, спущены/спущенны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Колёса моего велика **спущены**.* Это краткое прилагательное, качественная характеристика (в них нет воздуха).

*Её стандарты **спущены**.* Это краткое прилагательное, качественная характеристика (стали низкими).

*Коты, когда я пришёл, были, к счастью, **спущены**.* Краткое причастие (котов спустили с дерева).

**Пояснение**

В данном случае формы краткого причастия и прилагательного **совпадают**, что видно по словарю.

**Орфографический словарь**: спущенный; **кр. ф. -ен, -ена**

**[Розенталь, пункт 7](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62)**

**Примечание.** Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — **с одним н,** **подобно причастиям**, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола: заплаканные глаза — глаза заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; поношенное платье — платье поношено.

Answer (score 0):

***Колёса моего велика спущены.***

***Её стандарты спущены.***

***Коты, когда я пришёл, были, к счастью, спущены.***

*Спущены* — краткое причастие, образованное от глагола *спускать*. Пишется с одной Н, т. к. это краткое причастие, а краткие причастия всегда пишутся с одной Н.

Comment: Глагол спустить имеет 10 значений, вы какие имели в виду для каждого случая?

Comment: Как вы понимаете смысл второго предложения, да и первого с третьим тоже? И какая часть речи в каждом случае? Вопрос не представляется мне очень простым, информации в ответе мало.  Если там есть прилагательные, то почему они пишутся с одной Н?  Колеса могли спустить с верхнего этажа, из них кто-то мог спустить воздух, пока велик был без присмотра. Или камера дырявая. Детектив можно написать про одни колеса.

Comment: Так в любом случае с двумя Н. Я прочитал все значения.

Comment: Вот и разберите каждое предложение и докажите, что это так. Я вот вообще не понимаю значения некоторых слов. Так нельзя отвечать, ноль информации. Здесь есть прилагательные с качественным значением или нет? Почему их нет, докажите это? А если есть, то почему одно Н?  Расшифруйте, пожалуйста, словарь РАН http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=спущенный

Comment: @Sharon Ноль информации? Я так не думаю. А если вам не нравится, вставляйте свой ответ.

Comment: Я стараюсь улучшить и уточнить ваш ответ. Пока я увидела в РАН указанную информацию, она совпадает с вашим ответом.  Но там говорится про прич. или прил.?  Помогите разобраться. И еще я сомневаюсь в стилистике, так как смысл не совсем понимаю. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Максим, это хорошо, что вы так уверенно отвечаете, но не торопитесь. Большинство ваших ответов ничем не подкреплены. Вот представьте, что их читают школьники или те, кто не знают правил. Поверим Максиму? Который сказал, что так правильно, а так нет, что так всегда, а так никогда.